# XPath formula for an uncommon second URL attribute in <img> element

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

Having difficulty to get the correct XPath to scrape the real URL of any image of my Scoop.it topic. Here is the code excerpt centered on one image. Other images are treated the same way.

```
<div class="thisistherealimage"  >
    <img id="Here a specific image ID" width="467" height="412" 
    class="postDisplayedImage lazy"
    src="/resources/img/white.gif" 
    data-original="https://img.scoop.it/jKj7v6ojzPtACT6EaeztHTl72eJkfbmt4t8yenImKBVvK0kTmF0xjctABnaLJIm9"
    alt="Here an alternative text" style="width:467; height: 412;" />
```

So, in this code sample, I dont want to scrape "/resources/img/white.gif" but the URL following the "data-original" attribute!

I'd like to capture the the `data-original` attribute, not only to capture it when it contains a URL.

As an XPath beginner, I've tried `//div[contains(@class,'thisistherealimage')]/img[contains(@class,'postDisplayedImage')][contains(@class,'lazy')]`! 
But it's not specific to `data-original` attribute. Isn't it?

Any advice?

Comment: Do you _always_ want to capture the `data-original` attribute, or do you only want to capture it when it contains a URL?

Comment: So what XPath do you use to obtain the value of the `src` attribute? Then change `src` to `data-original`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `data-original`, you can access like this:

```
//div[contains(@class,'thisistherealimage')]/img[contains(@class,'postDisplayedImage') and contains(@class,'lazy')]/@data-original
```

Comment: Hum... i see it works inside my "XPath Helper Chrome extension" but not in the tool I use (ScrapeStom), wich doesn't scrape anything with it. Could be the tool problem. Thanks for your help indeed!